# In Colossians 2:2 what translation issues are involved with ESV putting "in Christ" where the NKJV puts "both of the Father and of Christ"?

Tags: colossians

**Colossians 2:2 ESV**

> "...and the knowledge of God's mystery, which is Christ."

**Colossians 2:2 NKJV**

> "...to the knowledge of the mystery of God, both of the Father and of Christ."

A. Why are they different?

B. Are they fundamentally saying the same or different things? Is the mystery Christ and His incarnation, or is the mystery that God is both Father and Son [2 persons]?

Comment: How many times in scripture is 'Father' coupled with 'Christ' ? (Rather than 'Father' and 'Son'.) I would suggest that as a pointer to the accuracy of manuscripts that contain the coupling. Compare to the wording 'Father' and 'Word' in the dubious Johannine comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matter in Col 2:2 is not a translation matter but a textual matter.  The extant MSS contain several variants of the last phrase:

- μυστηρίου τοῦ Θεοῦ, Χριστοῦ (= mystery of God, Christ) as per UBS5/NA28, W&H, etc
- μυστηρίου τοῦ Θεοῦ (= mystery of God) as per some MSS
- μυστηρίου τοῦ Θεοῦ καὶ πατρὸς καὶ τοῦ Χριστοῦ (mystery of God and [the] Father and of Christ) as per TR & Byzantine text
- μυστηρίου τοῦ Θεοῦ ἐν τοῦ Χριστοῦ (mystery of God in and of Christ) as per some MSS
- μυστηρίου τοῦ Θεοῦ πατρὸς τοῦ Χριστοῦ (mystery of God [the] Father [and] of Christ, as per some MSS

... plus several more.  That is, there are many variations of the text at this point.  See the huge amount of information in UBS5 for the details of which MSS support which reading.

Bruce Metzger in his "Textual Commentary on the GNT" has this to say about this verse:

> Among what at first sight seems to be bewildering variety of variant
> readings, the one adopted for the text is plainly to be preferred (a)
> because of the strong external testimony (P46, B, Hiliary, Pelegaius,
> Ps-Jerome) and (b) because it alone provides an adequate explanation
> of the other readings as various attempts to ameliorate the syntactic
> ambiguity of τοῦ Θεοῦ, Χριστοῦ.